How to use shared react-native code in turborepo
I am re-writing our react-native App in new Arch using turborepo for code sharing as the previous version had a lot of issues. What I am trying to do is have following workspaces
__
  | apps
  |  |__ App1
  |  |__ App2
  |
  | packages
     |__ native-ui

Our apps have a lot of common code that I would like to add to the native-ui folder so that we can avoid rewriting it.
What I have tried is copy the ui folder and update the package.json to look like this
{
    "name": "@repo/native-ui",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "exports": {
        "./button": "./src/button.tsx",
        "./card": "./src/card.tsx",
        "./code": "./src/code.tsx"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "build": "tsup",
        "dev": "tsup --watch",
        "clean": "rm -rf dist",
        "lint": "eslint . --max-warnings 0",
        "generate:component": "turbo gen react-component"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "react-native": "0.74.1",
        "tsup": "^8.0.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@repo/eslint-config": "workspace:*",
        "@repo/typescript-config": "workspace:*",
        "@turbo/gen": "^1.12.4",
        "@types/eslint": "^8.56.5",
        "@types/node": "^20.11.24",
        "@types/react": "^18.2.0",
        "eslint": "^8.19.0",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "typescript": "5.0.4"
    }
}

And added this newly created local-package to the App1.
But it throws the following Error
error: Error: Unable to resolve module @babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault from packages/native-ui/src/button.tsx: @babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  ../../packages/native-ui/node_modules
  ../../node_modules
> 1 | import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
    | ^
  2 | import React from 'react'
  3 |
  4 | const Button = () => {
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (node_modules/.pnpm/metro@0.80.9/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:138:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (node_modules/.pnpm/metro@0.80.9/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:231:43)
    at node_modules/.pnpm/metro@0.80.9/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:156:21
    at resolveDependencies (node_modules/.pnpm/metro@0.80.9/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/buildSubgraph.js:42:25)
    at visit (node_modules/.pnpm/metro@0.80.9/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/buildSubgraph.js:83:30)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
    at async visit (node_modules/.pnpm/metro@0.80.9/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/buildSubgraph.js:92:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 2)
    at async visit (node_modules/.pnpm/metro@0.80.9/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/buildSubgraph.js:92:5)

It seems like metro was unable to resolve 'react-native' because it is a symlink. I have already added the flag unstable_enableSymlinks to metro-config.

I'm using Turbo as a monorepo and modifying their basic example. I'm working on a similar multi-app project using a NextJS app and a React Native app. In the packages folder I'm creating framework-specific components based on the ui directory from the basic example. Each component library shares CSS and JavaScript resources in another directory inside packages.
Long story short, getting React Naitve to work in a monorepo like Turbo using 'npx react-native@latest init' takes some additional configuration. Here are the steps I followed to get it working.

Modify the metro.config.js inside the React Naive app (e.g. 'my-monorepo/apps/ReactNaitveApp/metro.config.js). with the following:

    const {getDefaultConfig, mergeConfig} = require('@react-native/metro-config');

    const path = require('path');
    const workspaceRoot = path.resolve(__dirname, '../..');
    const projectRoot = __dirname;

    const config = getDefaultConfig(projectRoot, {requireConfigFile: false});

    config.watchFolders = [workspaceRoot];

    config.resolver.nodeModulesPaths = [
      path.resolve(workspaceRoot, 'node_modules'),
      path.resolve(projectRoot, 'node_modules'),
    ];

    config.resolver.disableHierarchicalLookup = true;

    module.exports = mergeConfig(getDefaultConfig(projectRoot), config);


Install @babel/runtime in the root of your monorepo (e.g. at the root run npm i @babel/runtime).

Copy the babel.config from 'my-monorepo/apps/ReactNaitveApp/' to 'my-monorepo/'
I found the code for the metro-config modification on an issue in Turbo's Github repo. So far it's working.


